# In Facebook Marketing API, how can I get the estimated audience size with a combination of demo conditions?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, target-audience

In Facebook Marketing API, how can I get the estimated audience size by a combination of demo standard? Which endpoint should I use and how to write the html get request?

For example, I want to know how big is the audience size of people who live in US, age between 14-35, female, interest in {baseball,...}

I see that on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.9

you can get the audience size within one specific interest, but I want to know the audience size within a combination of conditions.

[Here is the number I am trying to get from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ScHU.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

```
var geoLocation = ["USA", "MA", "FR"];
var adAccountId = act_12354891531684;
var age = [18, 65];


https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/'+adAccountId+'/reachestimate?fields=users,estimate_ready,unsupported&targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":'+geoLocation+'},"age_min":'+age[0]+',"age_max":'+age[1]+'}&access_token=XXXXxxx
```

it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

got this work out!

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_ADACCOUNTID/delivery_estimate?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&optimization_goal=POST_ENGAGEMENT&targeting_spec={“geo_locations":{"location_types": ["home","recent"],"countries": ["US"]},"age_min":18,"age_max":65,"publisher_platforms": ["facebook"],"facebook_positions": ["feed"],"device_platforms": ["mobile","desktop"],"targeting_optimization":"none","flexible_spec": [{"interests": [{"id":"6003107902433","name":"Association football (Soccer)"},{"id":"6003087413192","name":"Baseball"}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

For the number you are looking for the correct end point is in fact /reachestimate and pass the targeting spec as with delivery_estimate.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/